# Resources allocation algorithm variant

Tags: algorithm, graph, resources, allocation, bipartite

Suppose we have producers and consumers of some resource. For producers we know how much they produce and for consumers we know how much they consume. We want to assign products to consumers such that the maximal number of consumers are satisfied - they consume as much as they can. We also have pairs producer-consumer, which tell us which producer can give product to which consumer.

(The problem can also be described as bipartite graph, where one part are producers, second one consumers. All vertices have values, and we want to find a flow from producers to consumers such that it maximize number of consumers which consume as much as they can.)

I have been thinking about this problem for some time but I can't think about polynomial algorithm to solve it. Maybe it is in NP?

Comment: It sounds like standard assignment problem which [Hungarian algoritm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) solves.

Comment: Considering the bipartite nature of this problem, you can model it as a game theory over bipartite network. Basically, you will have two sets representing the producers and the consumers with a number representing consumption and production limits. For every consumer, an edge is formed between one consumer and one producer ( the consumer should select the producer based on its consumption limit).

Comment: The main difference is that standard assignment problem is about minimizing costs where each task (we have consumer instead of task) must be satisfied. We want to maximize number of satisfied consumers (or tasks). Also in our problem, products of one producer can be assigned to many consumers, which is not the case of assignment problem.

Comment: M.M: I don't understand it. You want to form a bipartite graph with edges showing which producer can supply resource to which consumer am I right? But how the production and consumption limits will be represented? And what algorithm will solve this problem?